# storing the filename in a integer variable in java

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have a folder with files and name of file are integers like 110045, 56789449 etc.files contains text values. I want to store the filename as key and its content as value in a treemap. but it gives number format exception:

```
public  void ReadDir()throws Exception{

  Map<Integer,List<String>> tweet = new TreeMap<Integer,List<String>>();         
  File dr = new File("/home/abc/NetBeansProjects/cleantweet");

  if(dr.isDirectory()){
    String dirlist[] = dr.list();
    int nfiles= dirlist.length;
    System.out.print("no 0f user tweet files   "+ nfiles +"\n");

    for(int i =0;i<nfiles;i++){
      tw.assignVal(dirlist[i]);
    }
}

public void assignVal(String filename) throws Exception {
    FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("/home/abc/NetBeansProjects/cleantweet/"+filename);
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
    String str="";
    while ((str = br1.readLine()) != null) {
      assignment.put(str,rand.nextInt(topics-1)+1);
      recsys.tweet.put(Integer.parseInt(filename),list);// this line gives error
    }
}
```

Comment: Means that your `filename` contains something other than digits (for example, spaces).

Comment: You should debug what exactly is the content of "filename". Maybe there is a non-digit char in (for example spaces or the file extension).

Comment: You should be specific about your errors.  Was this a compile-time error?  A NullPointerException?

Comment: no filename is only integer. no non-digit char is there.

Comment: And watch out for "hidden" files in that directory. "." or ".." may be found there, depending on your system, or some ".something"s.

Comment: its a runtime error numberformatexception

Comment: debug and print out every char including its ascii-code, testing is better than believing.

Comment: yes.. exception is for file 10008949~  i think its a hidden file. how to remove such files from directory

Comment: java.io.File.isHidden() gives you a test to filter such files out.

Answer (score 2):

Your input may be all digits, but if the numeric equivalent is out of range of a 32-bit signed integer, you'll get this error.

Your input must be in the range `-2147483648` to `2147483647`.

If you have values larger than these values, try using `Long` to parse a 64-bit signed `long` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you should check if the filename is too long, so an Integer would be to small for that number

Comment: This is probably the reason, if those integers are Twitter's tweet IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    recsys.tweet.put(Integer.parseInt(filename),list);
} catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
    System.out.println("This is not an integer: \"" + filename + "\".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `filename` is as 102.txt
so try this code:

```
try {
 recsys.tweet.put(Integer.parseInt(filename.substring(0, filename.length - 4)),list);
} catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
 System.out.println("This is not an integer: \"" + filename + "\".");
}
```

if there still error, it may be because of large number.
so you can use:

```
recsys.tweet.put(Long.parseLong(filename.substring(0, filename.length - 4)),list);
//or use BigInteger
recsys.tweet.put(new BigInteger(filename.substring(0, filename.length - 4)),list);
```

You also read hidden file that contains characters, so you need to use this code:

```
if(dr.isDirectory() && !dr.isHidden()){
}
```